# Why does a transitive class that is closed under Gödel operations and is almost universal satisfy Separation?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

In Jech's *Set Theory*, Theorem 13.9 states the following.

> A transitive class $M$ is an inner model of ZF if and only if it is closed under Gödel operations and is almost universal, i.e., every subset $X\subseteq M$ is included in some $Y\in M$.

In the proof, he states that all axioms except Separation are simple enough to verify (which seems to be true, although a few of them seem to require Separation, which I will elaborate on momentarily). He then spends the rest of the proof establishing Separation by induction on the number of quantifiers in the relevant formulas.

The general outline of the proof is that given a formula $\varphi(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ and a set $X\in M$, we want to show $Y=\{u\in X:\varphi^M(u)\}\in M$. Supposing $\varphi$ has $k$ quantifiers, we first define $\bar\varphi(u_1,\dots,u_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_k)$ as $\varphi$ with each $\exists x$ replaced by $\exists x\in Y_j$ (and similarly for $\forall$). We want to prove by induction on the number of quantifiers that we can always find $Y_1,\dots,Y_k$ such that
$$\varphi^M(u_1,\dots,u_k)\leftrightarrow\bar\varphi(u_1,\dots,u_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_k).$$
Then we can use $\Delta_0$-Separation to finish.

In the induction step, he lets $\varphi(u)=\exists v\, \psi(u,v)$. He states by the Collection Principle (6.5) applied to the formula $v\in M\land \psi^M(u,v)$, we get a set $M_1$ such that $X\subseteq M_1\subseteq M$ and for all $u\in X$,
$$(\exists v\in M\, \varphi^M(u,v))\leftrightarrow(\exists v\in M_1 \, \varphi^M(u,v)).$$

My confusion arises from the fact that you need Replacement to prove the Collection Principle, but establishing Replacement requires Separation! It appears, then, that the proof is circular. What am I missing?

For completeness, here's my proof that Replacement holds:

Let $F$ be a function on $M$ and $X\in M$. (Metamathematical) Replacement gives that $F(X)$ is a set, and since $F$ is a function on $M$ it must be a subset of $M$. Almost universality gives that $F(X)\subseteq Y$ for some $Y\in M$, and then $F(X)=\{u\in M:\exists x\in X \, F(x)=u\}$ is in $M$ by Separation.

Comment: You only need replacement in $V$ to do this proof. You do not need $M$ to be a model of replacement. This is your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of asking the question I managed to figure out an answer, but I've made it this far so I figured I'd leave it here for future documentation purposes.

The fact of the matter is that the Collection Principle only uses Replacement to deduce that the relevant $M_1$ is a set. In this context, this means we only need $M$ to satisfy Separation a priori if we want $M_1$ to be an element of $M$. However, we don't actually need that since the $v\in M$ part of the formula gives that $M_1\subseteq M$, which is sufficient for almost universality. So the metamathematical Collection Principle giving that $M_1$ is a set (not necessarily in $M$) suffices.